# Connecting 2 docker containers to the same TCP/IP or UNIX socket

Tags: docker, sockets, ansible

I have 2 docker containers and I would like to deploy them using Ansible. They are deployed in the same host. Also, I need these 2 docker containers to communicate with each other via socketing either it's a TCP/IP socket or UNIX domain socket. However, I do not know what is the best practice to allow them to do so.

Comment: The tool to do these things is `docker-compose`. Have you had a look at it? Is it an option?

Answer (score 0):

You could check network settings in docker-compose command
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

I have a running Zabbix configured in this way, in which I had to set-up static IPs in order to link all the 3 containers in a stable way even after a server restart.
Network details are at the bottom.

```
version: '2'
services:
    zabbix-server4:
      container_name: zabbix-server4
      image: zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql:alpine-4.0.5
      networks:
        zbx_net:
          aliases:
            - zabbix-server4
          ipv4_address: 172.16.238.5

    zabbix-web4:
      container_name: zabbix-web4
      image: zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-mysql:alpine-4.0.5
      ports: 
        - 127.0.0.1:11011:80
      links:
        - zabbix-server4
      networks:
        zbx_net:
          aliases:
            - zabbix-web4
          ipv4_address: 172.16.238.10

    zabbix-agent4:
      container_name: zabbix-agent4
      image: zabbix/zabbix-agent:alpine-4.0.5
      links:
        - zabbix-server4
      networks:
        zbx_net:
          aliases:
            - zabbix-agent4
          ipv4_address: 172.16.238.15


networks:
  zbx_net:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.enable_ipv6: "false"
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 172.16.238.0/24
        gateway: 172.16.238.1
```